# Delphi form won't show - suspecting halted loading

Tags: delphi-xe2, vcl

I'm having trouble with a Delphi project (MyProject) of mine. The problem which (as always) appeared over night without my involvement, basically boils down to the form not being shown. I've checked the .dpr-file, and it looks like this:

```
// Removed code above for brevity
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

I checked the .dfm, and the form looks ok to me (I never realized before that the default setting for visibility for a form is false, and so I thought that was it - only to discover that setting visible to true did not solve my problem).

In other words, I've checked all the relevant settings I know of. So I created a new, freshly minted project (NewProject). The event log for the new project looks like this:

```
Thread Start: Thread ID: 6460. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Process Start: C:\code\NewProject.exe. Base Address: $00400000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: NewProject.exe. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00400000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: ntdll.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $778A0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: KERNEL32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76470000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: KERNELBASE.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $765C0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: OLEAUT32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76830000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: ole32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $752C0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: msvcrt.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76E70000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: GDI32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76DE0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: USER32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76730000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: ADVAPI32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $768C0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: SECHOST.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $752A0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: RPCRT4.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $754F0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: SspiCli.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74F80000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: CRYPTBASE.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74F70000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: LPK.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $77870000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: USP10.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76BE0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: MSIMG32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74320000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: VERSION.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74310000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: COMCTL32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74170000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: SHLWAPI.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76D00000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: SHELL32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $75740000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: WINSPOOL.DRV. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74110000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: IMM32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76960000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: MSCTF.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $75420000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: UxTheme.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74040000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: dwmapi.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $706E0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: WTSAPI32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $740F0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: WINSTA.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $740C0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Thread Start: Thread ID: 6928. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Thread Start: Thread ID: 484. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: BtMmHook.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $10000000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: PSAPI.DLL. No Debug Info. Base Address: $755E0000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: ole32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $04150000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Unload: ole32.dll. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: ole32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $04150000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Unload: ole32.dll. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
Module Load: CLBCatQ.DLL. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76F20000. Process NewProject.exe (1776)
```

while the misbehaving project outputs the following event log:

```
Thread Start: Thread ID: 6880. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Process Start: C:\code\MyProject\MyProject.exe. Base Address: $00400000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: MyProject.exe. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00400000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: ntdll.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $778A0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: KERNEL32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76470000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: KERNELBASE.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $765C0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: OLEAUT32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76830000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: ole32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $752C0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: msvcrt.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76E70000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: GDI32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76DE0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: USER32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76730000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: ADVAPI32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $768C0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: SECHOST.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $752A0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: RPCRT4.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $754F0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: SspiCli.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74F80000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: CRYPTBASE.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74F70000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: LPK.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $77870000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: USP10.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76BE0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: MSIMG32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74320000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: VERSION.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74310000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: SHFOLDER.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $70A10000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: SHELL32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $75740000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: SHLWAPI.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76D00000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: COMCTL32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74170000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: WININET.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $75180000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: Normaliz.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76CF0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: iertutil.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $769C0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: urlmon.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76610000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: COMDLG32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76D60000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: WINSPOOL.DRV. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74110000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: IMM32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76960000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: MSCTF.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $75420000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: UxTheme.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $74040000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: dwmapi.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $706E0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: WTSAPI32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $740F0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: WINSTA.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $740C0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Thread Start: Thread ID: 7888. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Thread Start: Thread ID: 6236. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: BtMmHook.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $10000000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
Module Load: PSAPI.DLL. No Debug Info. Base Address: $755E0000. Process MyProject.exe (7296)
```

I realize that there are good reasons why the two event logs doesn't look identical, and thus this may be, at best, a point in the right direction. Specifically, the failing project (MyProject) includes more libraries, which leads to more DLLs being loaded.

One thing got me thinking, though: the failing project stops loading after it loaded PSAPI.DLL, while the last thing the working project does before the form is displayed, is to load CLBCatQ.DLL.

Does this mean anything to anyone? What else can I do to dig further into the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any exception? Did you debug your units initialization sections?

Comment: No, no exception, so that's speaking against an unexpected halt in the execution ... It feels I'm grasping at straws here, but I've got to figure this one out.

Comment: What about stepping into your initialization sections?

Comment: Well, I did that (I thought). Seems like I f*#&ed up something in my TfrmMain-constructor. Thanks, jachguate, for asking the right questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Classic PEBKAC. The main form constructor was faulty, thus no form being shown.

Take home message: don't make a complex problem out of a simple one.